# django-pipeline and s3boto storage don't seem to work together

Tags: python, django, static-content, django-pipeline

I'm trying to use django-pipeline-1.1.27 with s3boto to compress and filter static files, and then upload them to an s3 bucket. If I just use:

```
PIPELINE_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineFinderStorage'
```

Then it works and I get a static folder with the nice versioned file that I configured. As soon as I switch to

```
PIPELINE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/my/virtual/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/my/virtual/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/my/virtual/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/my/virtual/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/my/virtual/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/management/commands/synccompress.py", line 39, in handle
    packager.pack_stylesheets(package, sync=sync, force=force)
  File "/my/virtual/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 52, in pack_stylesheets
    **kwargs)
  File "/my/virtual/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 60, in pack
    package['output'], package['paths'])
  File "/my/virtual/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/versioning/__init__.py", line 45, in need_update
    version = self.version(paths)
  File "/my/virtual/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/versioning/__init__.py", line 20, in version
    return getattr(self.versioner, 'version')(paths)
  File "/my/virtual/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/versioning/hash/__init__.py", line 37, in version
    buf = self.concatenate(paths)
  File "/my/virtual/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/versioning/hash/__init__.py", line 27, in concatenate
    return '\n'.join([self.read_file(path) for path in paths])
  File "/my/virtual/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/versioning/hash/__init__.py", line 31, in read_file
    file = storage.open(path, 'rb')
  File "/my/virtual/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 33, in open
    file = self._open(name, mode)
  File "/my/virtual/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 177, in _open
    raise IOError('File does not exist: %s' % name)
IOError: File does not exist: css/style.css
```

which is one of my **source** files. So why does pipeline no longer want to do the filter/concatenate/compress steps when I switch to s3boto storage?

It may be that I'm doing something. Here is other config in case it helps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'pipeline',
    'storages',
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATIC_ROOT = "/some/path/outside/django_project/deploy_static"
STATICFILES_DIRS = () # All statics in this site are in apps

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'
PIPELINE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

PIPELINE = True
PIPELINE_AUTO = True
PIPELINE_VERSION = True
PIPELINE_VERSION_PLACEHOLDER = 'VERSION'
PIPELINE_VERSIONING = 'pipeline.versioning.hash.SHA1Versioning'

PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'standard': {
        'source_filenames': (
          'css/style.css',
          ...
        ),
        'output_filename': 'css/all-VERSION.css',
        'extra_context': {
            'media': 'screen,projection',
        },
    }
}
```

My site is on Django 1.3.1.

The command I'm running is:

```
python manage.py synccompress --force
```

The AWS creds are also in settings, but that's moot because it's not even getting to that point.

**UPDATE** Added full stack and settings requested in comments

**UPDATE** At the request of the library author, I tried upgrading to the latest beta. Observations from that so far:

1. I don't know how to get versioned compressed files now
2. collectstatic leaves me with the compressed files *and* the originals
3. Still getting the same error from django-pipeline when boto storage is configured: it wants to send my *source* files to s3, but I can't even see where it's staging my assets. Nothing gets placed in STATIC_ROOT.

**UPDATE** I've created the simplest project that works for finder storage and then breaks with S3Boto. I've pushed it to github, and included a capture of the stacktrace.

https://github.com/estebistec/simple_pipeline
https://raw.github.com/estebistec/simple_pipeline/master/STACKTRACE

I would be ecstatic if I could be told I'm doing some really dumb and this should all just work.

Comment: What is your setup for ``STATIC_ROOT``, ``STATICFILES_DIRS`` and ``PIPELINE_ROOT`` ? Also full traceback would be useful !

Comment: Added full stack, STATIC_ROOT, and STATICFILES_DIRS. The *only* mention of PIPELINE_ROOT in the 1.1.27 docs is in an info box related to absolute paths, which I'm not using to locate the source files.

Comment: So is my empty STATICFILES_DIRS throwing it all off? Is PIPELINE_ROOT required regardless of when the documentation implies it should be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`django-pipeline 1.1.x` is a bit dumb about how you should use staticfiles, it prefers to have everything in one place.
I suggest you to try `django-pipeline 1.2` with latest `django-staticfiles` or `django 1.4`.

Use a custom like this :

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'your.app.S3PipelineStorage'
```

The code looks like this :

```
from staticfiles.storage import CachedFilesMixin

from pipeline.storage import PipelineMixin

from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage


class S3PipelineStorage(PipelineMixin, CachedFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
     pass
```

You can find how to fix your application, but there is still a bug with compiled files unless you use version 1.2c1 : https://gist.github.com/1999564

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put ellipses after the pipeline finder. I'm not *trying* to make it hard to give me help :/

Comment: Oh wow, did I miss the staticfiles dependency in the docs? I aborted from the 1.2 betas pretty quick because I could see it was using stuff not in django 1.3. I had no idea django-staticfiles was still be enhanced outside of django :/

Comment: Documentation always need improvements, don't hesitate to open github issues for documentation or else.

Comment: I think I'll do that once I see all of this working. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: How does versioning work with the 1.2 betas? I'm seeing sha1 versions on individual source files, but NOT on my aggregated/filtered files.

Comment: And, I'm getting the same error with 1.2. I've give this "everything in one place" a try, and add an entry to STTICFILES_DIRS. :/

Comment: Where does the hashing of the filecontents happen now?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll give this a try in a short while.

Comment: That did it. Versioning and all. Thanks! My only remaining functional issue is that pipeline sends *all* of the files to boto storage. Hopefully I can get some time soon and try to send some patches for this and or my confusion from the docs. Thanks again!

Comment: FYI, I'm hoping to return to the issue's I've had with pipeline when my projects move to django 1.4 (where the staticfiles/django mismatch should largely go away).

Comment: Also, if you felt this question provided any help with improving the doc or other issues in consuming the lib, do you mind give it an upvote?

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced this same error on a Django 1.6 project with `django-pipeline==1.3.23`, and the solution was simply removing the `PIPELINE_STORAGE` setting.

Answer (score 2):

There is another problem with similar error message that affects earlier and current version (1.5.4) of `django-pipeline`.

The error message is `IOError: File does not exist`, and it happens in `s3boto.py.open()` and `packager.pack_stylesheets()`. You might hit the problem if you use any of the compiler (Compass, Sass, Less etc). I suspect it would also affect JS compiler, but I have not confirmed.

In a nutshell, the compiler generates output file in the local static storage and the next steps, `compress` is trying to find the output in s3 storage.

If it affects you, you might want to take a look at https://github.com/cyberdelia/django-pipeline/issues/473. There are two pull-requests (patches), one made by skirsdeda and another made by thomasyip (me). Both might solve your problem. If you would like the compiled (but, pre-compressed) file to be copied to s3 and available to the app, the you would take thomasyip (me)'s patch.

Here is full Traceback for the problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apps/manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/thomas/Dev/Project/main-server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/thomas/Dev/Project/main-server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/thomas/Dev/Project/main-server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/thomas/Dev/Project/main-server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/thomas/Dev/Project/main-server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 533, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Users/thomas/Dev/Project/main-server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 171, in handle_noargs
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/Users/thomas/Dev/Project/main-server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 117, in collect
    for original_path, processed_path, processed in processor:
  File "/Users/thomas/Dev/Project/main-server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/storage.py", line 26, in post_process
    packager.pack_stylesheets(package)
  File "/Users/thomas/Dev/Project/main-server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 96, in pack_stylesheets
    variant=package.variant, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/thomas/Dev/Project/main-server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 106, in pack
    content = compress(paths, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/thomas/Dev/Project/main-server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py", line 73, in compress_css
    css = self.concatenate_and_rewrite(paths, output_filename, variant)
  File "/Users/thomas/Dev/Project/main-server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py", line 137, in concatenate_and_rewrite
    content = self.read_text(path)
  File "/Users/thomas/Dev/Project/main-server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py", line 220, in read_text
    content = self.read_bytes(path)
  File "/Users/thomas/Dev/Project/main-server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py", line 214, in read_bytes
    file = staticfiles_storage.open(path)
  File "/Users/thomas/Dev/Project/main-server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 35, in open
    return self._open(name, mode)
  File "/Users/thomas/Dev/Project/main-server/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 366, in _open
    raise IOError('File does not exist: %s' % name)
IOError: File does not exist: sheets/sass/sheets.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the answers, you could use GZIP as well when compressing:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import CachedFilesMixin

from pipeline.storage import PipelineMixin

from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage


class S3PipelineStorage(PipelineMixin, CachedFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.gzip = True
        super(S3PipelineStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Using the settings as follows:

```
COMPRESS_STORAGE = STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'my.apps.main.S3PipelineStorage'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this seemed to work for everyone else.  I followed the solution above and kept getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 24, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 168, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
    for original_path, processed_path, processed in processor:
  File "python3.4/site-packages/pipeline/storage.py", line 26, in post_process
    packager.pack_stylesheets(package)
  File "python3.4/site-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 96, in pack_stylesheets
    variant=package.variant, **kwargs)
  File "python3.4/site-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 105, in pack
    paths = self.compile(package.paths, force=True)
  File "python3.4/site-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 99, in compile
    return self.compiler.compile(paths, force=force)
  File "python3.4/site-packages/pipeline/compilers/__init__.py", line 56, in compile
    return list(executor.map(_compile, paths))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 549, in result_iterator
    yield future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 402, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 354, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 54, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "python3.4/site-packages/pipeline/compilers/__init__.py", line 42, in _compile
    outdated = compiler.is_outdated(input_path, output_path)
  File "python3.4/site-packages/pipeline/compilers/__init__.py", line 85, in is_outdated
    return self.storage.modified_time(infile) > self.storage.modified_time(outfile)
  File "python3.4/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 480, in modified_time
    return parse_ts(entry.last_modified)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'last_modified'
```

It wasn't until I came across [this solution](http://jeanphix.me/2012/02/08/django-heroku-compressor-storages/) that I started to find what worked for me.  Here's the storage that I ended up using that saved the file locally as well as in S3 which got me passed all errors:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import ManifestFilesMixin
from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class
from pipeline.storage import PipelineMixin
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage


class StaticStorage(PipelineMixin, ManifestFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    """Custom storage for static content."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StaticStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.local_storage = get_storage_class(
            'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage')()

    def save(self, name, content):
        name = super(StaticStorage, self).save(name, content)
        self.local_storage._save(name, content)
        return name
```

Comment: So this was originally for an older version of pipeline. Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to edit the question title to put a version in and make that clear :/