# How to make django-storage and django-pipeline work together

Tags: python, django, django-storage, django-pipeline

I want to use both django-pipeline and django-storage on heroku for a personal app. Using only django-pipeline works perfectly, using only django-storage works like a charm but I don't manage to get both of them work together :(

When you read docs, you will find this to make both work with collecstatic:

**Django-pipeline:**

```
settings.py
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'
PIPELINE_CSS = {
'app': {
    'source_filenames': (
        'css/*',
    ),
    'output_filename': 'css/min.css',
    'variant': 'datauri',
},
}
```

**Django-Storage**

```
settings.py
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 's3storages.StaticStorage'

s3storages.py
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
StaticStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(
      bucket='app_name', 
      location='assets'
)
```

So both app needs to set STATICFILE_STORAGE; when i set storage for amazon s3; django-pipeline doesn't create min.css and min.js...

So i found [this solution on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608969/django-pipeline-and-s3boto-storage-dont-seem-to-work-together) and did the following:

```
from staticfiles.storage import CachedFilesMixin
from pipeline.storage import PipelineMixin
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class S3PipelineStorage(PipelineMixin, CachedFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
pass

# Define bucket and folder for static files.
StaticStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(
      bucket='app_name', 
      location='assets'
)
```

Now, each time I use collectstatic command, static files are send to amazon S3 but django-pipeline min.css and min.js are not sent... There is no trace of them in my STATIC_ROOT directory also....

Do you know how I can use both together?

**EDIT 1:**

Now in I have this: (I changed s3storage :) )

```
settings.py
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 's3storages.StaticStorage'

s3storage.py
from staticfiles.storage import CachedFilesMixin
from pipeline.storage import PipelineMixin
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class S3PipelineStorage(PipelineMixin, CachedFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
pass

# Define bucket and folder for static files.
StaticStorage = lambda: S3PipelineStorage(
      bucket='app_name', 
      location='assets'
)
```

Comment: I would fork django-pipeline and add the option of PIPELINE_STATICFILES_STORAGE and send a pull request explaining the need for the specific option.

Comment: Did you set ``STATICFILES_STORAGE`` to point to ``S3PipelineStorage``?

Comment: Oups i made an Edit of my question to answer you.

Answer (score 1):

Setup `STATICFILES_STORAGE` to : `s3storage.S3PipelineStorage`.

Use `settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME` and `settings.AWS_LOCATION` to configure S3.